# Color fillable design to be distributed

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

I have a design of vector shapes (in Illustrator) that I would like to send to friends to color fill.  Is there an app I can place the design into that someone else can fill?

Comment: Is that like a electric coloring book? Are  flood fills with solid colors ok? (=are there watertight black lines to stop the flood?). Obviously you search some free software. If you can send PNGs instead of vector data you would have much more easy to use options. PNGs have a bonus: Your drawings are not easy to reuse because they are not vector data.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the way to go is a raster free program.

Microsoft Paint? Fresh Paint?

Gimp?

Krita?

My Paint?

Project DogWaffle?

https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=free+painting+program

Comment: Howabout javascript on svg